# Delete *ngFor line depending on id

Tags: angular

Working with Angular 8 I have an issue, I have an `*ngFor` which render some values, inside those values there's an id which is different from the index.

I'm having problems to delete a line depending on the **id** and not the **index**, does anyone know how should I do it ?

Here's the JSON I'm using : [image: JSON]

I'm trying to delete line from `projects.data.id`

Here's my delete function :

```
token = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('token'));
currentIndex: number;

deleteProject(){
   const index_id = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("index_id")).value
    return this.httpClient.delete(`http://test.url${index_id}?token=${this.token.token}`)
     .subscribe(
       data => {
         console.log("DELETE PROJECT DONE",data);
       },
       error => {
        console.log("DELETE PROJECT FAILED", error)
       })
 }
```

My HTML :

```
<div  class="projectsContainer container" >
 <li   class="flex-row bb pt5 pb5 flex-noshrink mh20" *ngFor="let p of Projects.projects.data;let i 
   of index;" value="{{p.id}}" [value]="i"  >
  <a  class="flex2"  (change)="currentIndex = $event.target.value" >{{i.id}} {{p.code}}</a>
 </li>
</div>
```

Thank's for your time and your help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `deleteProject()` pass `id` like this `(click)="deleteProject(p.id)`

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-itzt7q?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

.html

```
<li   class="flex-row bb pt5 pb5 flex-noshrink mh20" *ngFor="let p of Projects.projects.data;let i 
   of index;" value="{{p.id}}" [value]="i"  >
  <a  class="flex2"  (change)="currentIndex = $event.target.value" >{{i.id}} {{p.code}}</a>
   <button (click)="deleteProject(p.id)">Delete</button>
</li>
```

.ts

```
deleteProject(id){

    this.httpClient.delete(`http://test.url${id}?token=${this.token.token}`)
     .subscribe(
       data => {
         console.log("DELETE PROJECT DONE",data);
       },
       error => {
        console.log("DELETE PROJECT FAILED", error)
       })
 }
```

Comment: I forgot to post the button from my HTML and you got it sorted out! Thank's for the answer it works as expected, I don't know why I didn't tought of that before. Thank you!

Comment: It happens.. You are welcome. Accept the answer if this was useful :)